# spring MVC3 errors Could not instantiate bean class [java.util.List]: Specified class is an interface Occasional

Tags: java, spring

#### I am using spring MVC3, I found code like below:

```
@Controller
class IndexController
{
    @ModelAttribute("allTags")
    public List<ArticleTag> allTags()
    {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

#### Sometimes errors with message

## (Not always)

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [java.util.List]: Specified class is an interface] with root cause
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [java.util.List]: Specified class is an interface
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:101)
        at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:132)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:81)
        at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:103)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:75)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:156)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
        at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelFactory.invokeModelAttributeMethods(ModelFactory.java:123)
        at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelFactory.initModel(ModelFactory.java:97)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:614)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
```

#### Someone Says, List is a interface, plz use ArrayList or LinkedList instead

## But, My Question is, Why the code above is not always eror?

#### When the error above occured, not matter how to refresh the page, error continues, nevery disappear！But, If you restart tomcat, you have a good opportunity to walk through this error!If no error like above occur,it never occurs util next tomcat restart!

### Same as @ModelAttribute with type int or Integer, it will very likely error, but on some host, It never occurs

Answer (score -1):

Change the code as below

```
public ArticleTag allTags()
```

For more information, please refer to below link

[http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/nosql/724397-mapping-exception-with-mongodb-aggregation-framework][1]

Also refer to Mongo Issue fixed

[https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-229]

Comment: Where is the code you are refering to? Please don't post answers that only contain links to pages, because their content can change and leave the whole answer useless

Comment: @NicoHaase i have updated the comments, please refer it